# Linq to Entities Search Algorithm

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm implementing a search that will take six possible (but not required) user inputs and then try to match them to some entities.

I think the issue I have come up against is that EF and SQL Server think of nulls as two very different things.

Idea: select an entity where columnA = (if columnA is null then columnA (or null) else searchTerm). The search terms are a mix of ints and strings.

Some code:

```
entities= (from c in context.Entities
           where c.ColumnA == (searchTermA ?? v.ColumnA)
           where c.ColumnB == (searchTermB ?? v.ColumnB)
           select new
           {
               v.Property,
           }).ToList();
```

If all columns do not contain nulls, entities are returned. However, I do not get expected results if the column has nulls.

How can I work around this?

Richard

Comment: Where does the `v` come from? Should it be a `c` as well?

Comment: yes all the same.. e's, v's, c's... they're everywhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i used to handle null values. It was the only way i could get the right results.

```
((searchTermA.HasValue) ? (c.ColumnA == searchTermA) : true)
```

Comment: I'll accept this as it's very close to a possible solution I worked out banging my head on my kitchen table later on. I tried:

searchTermA == null ? true : v.ColumnA == searchTermA

I'll work out which combo of both works best today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have the function accept a `Predicate<T>` and do the construction of the filter on the UI side.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is this one:

```
var query = from c in context.Entities;

if  (searchTermA != null) {
    query = query.Where(c => c.ColumnA == searchTermA);
}

// Rest of your conditions defined in the same way.

var entities = query.Select(c => new { c.Property }).ToList();
```